# Wrapper view in SwiftUI around a subview that's determined using a switch case

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `WrapperView` struct that takes in a `childView` that conforms to the `View` protocol.

```
struct WrapperView<C: View>: View {
    let childView: C

    init(_ childView: () -> (C)) {
        self.childView = childView()
    }

    var body: some View {
        childView
    }
}
```

I have another struct called `RealView` that has a function called `bodyView` that returns a wrapped child view based on a condition.

```
struct TextAView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("A")
    }
}

struct TextBView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("B")
    }
}

struct TextCView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("C")
    }
}

struct RealView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        bodyView()
    }
    
    private func bodyView() -> some View {
        let type = 1
        
        var bodyChild: any View
        
        switch type {
        case 1:
            bodyChild = TextAView()
        case 2:
            bodyChild = TextBView()
        case 3:
            bodyChild = TextCView()
        default:
            bodyChild = EmptyView()
        }
        
        return WrapperView {
            //Text("Hello") <- this works
            bodyChild // <- this doesn't work! Error is: Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that this is because `bodyChild` has a type of `any View` but the compiler requires a type of `View`. How do I fix this so that I can conditionally return a `bodyChild`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is by involving `ViewBuilder` so that Swift can infer a (big, complicated) type for `bodyChild` instead of using an existential. An easy way to get `ViewBuilder` involved here is to wrap a `Group` around the `switch`:

```
private func bodyView() -> some View {
    let type = 1

    let bodyChild = Group {
        switch type {
        case 1:
            TextAView()
        case 2:
            TextBView()
        case 3:
            TextCView()
        default:
            EmptyView()
        }
    }

    return WrapperView {
        bodyChild
    }
}
```

Above, Swift infers that `bodyChild` has the type `Group<_ConditionalContent<_ConditionalContent<TextAView, TextBView>, _ConditionalContent<TextCView, EmptyView>>>`.